# SSPI negotiation failed error after upgrading ASP.NET site to .NET 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-7, wcf-security

This error comes up when the site is deployed on the server, but works correctly on my dev box.

Let me provide some quick background on how everything is setup.

The application (**WebApp**) is deployed to a Windows Server 2008 SP2 running IIS 7.0. There are two applications within the site: **WebApp** and **WebService**. The server is not part of a domain, but is on the local network.

**WebService** contains a WCF webservice (svc) and has not be modified. I can connect to this and use it as expected.

I upgraded **WebApp** to ASP.NET 4 from ASP.NET 3.5 sp1, which has a client proxy to the WCF webservice (generated by adding a service reference). Prior to upgrading everything worked correctly. After upgrading, I can run it and use it correctly from my dev box (on a domain) and it can use **WebService** as expected. When I deploy the site to the server and access it, I get the following error (**updated with the stack trace, only included the first line after each message**):

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) negotiation failed.]
System.ServiceModel.Security.WindowsSspiNegotiation.GetOutgoingBlob(Byte[] incomingBlob, ChannelBinding channelbinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy protectionPolicy) +3705927

[SecurityNegotiationException: SOAP security negotiation with 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' for target 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' failed. See inner exception for more details.]
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9464367

[HttpException (0x80004005): SOAP security negotiation with 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' for target 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' failed. See inner exception for more details.]
System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +9028953

[HttpException (0x80004005): SOAP security negotiation with 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' for target 'http://server.mydoamin.com/WebService/TestService.svc' failed. See inner exception for more details.]
System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8950644
```

The only change I made in IIS was to set the app pool to .NET 4.

I've tested and can connect and use the **WebService** from a non-domain computer without any issues. And it works fine from my dev box (on the domain).

I am using wsHttpBinding and authenticating with a username/password of a local (to the server) windows user account. I set the user/password on the ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential property of the client proxy.

Here is my security config under the client binding (it's all auto-gen, I didn't modify it from adding the service reference):

```
<security mode="Message">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
  <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true"/>
</security>
```

Again, everything works correctly if the asp.net site is run from somewhere other than on the server.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What is the inner exception? Stack trace?

Comment: I've added all the messages in the stack trace.

Comment: Can you RDP into the server? If so, can you open the URL of the service in a browser, Does it prompt you for credentials?

Comment: I have RDP'd in and it does not prompt me for any credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-install the .net4 distribution file.
Sometimes, when you enable some .net3.5 function will cause strange problems.